# Scrolling inside an android surfaceview

Tags: java, android, android-view

I'm working on an android game, and just recently made the step to SurfaceView from View, to ensure smooth performance.

However, scrolling seems to work strangely. While using view, i could just draw stuff off-screen, and use ScrollBy to bring it into the viewport. Surfaceview seems to do absolutely nothing when doing so.

How can i make scrolling work in SurfaceView, in a manner similar to View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used canvas.translate( -this.getScrollX(), -this.getScrollY() );